Rambam contradiction
Rambam in Hilchot Issurei Biah 22:18 says that there’s nothing more hard for most of the nation to keep than the Arayot commandments. Around that same area, he also quotes a Gemara that says that “most people fall by theft, few people fall in Arayot, and all fall in Lashon Hara.” This Gemara seems to say that only a minority of the nation fall regarding Arayot. So why did Rambam just before say that Arayot is the hardest command for most of the nation?

The question assumes that the more difficult something is the less people who will keep it. That isn't known to true and there is no reason to assume the Rambam was of that opinion.

@Schmerel but he specifically says it’s difficult for “most” of the nation

I don't see the contradiction.

Your question is addressed by the Prisha (EH 25:2) and the Birkei Yosef 25:1. Essentially, they both explain that the inclination for aryaos is extremely strong ,and indeed is very hard to keep. However, the majority aren't nichshal in aryaos itself ,rather the majority have to battle with it.
Text of Birkei Yosef :


Short and simple, thanks!

Perhaps we can differentiate between the level of desire on the one hand and the percentage of people that succumb to said desire on the other.
In halacha 18 Rambam is describing how difficult it is for folks to keep their distance from arayos as it is the most attractive and seductive aveirah. In the following halacha he says that folks feel a strong pull towards arayos and theft and that ultimately most slip up with theft and only a minority with arayos. That is to say that ultimately, despite how attractive arayos is, and it is more attractive than theft, due to its severity most people are able to abstain, despite the difficulty and overwhelming desire for it. As opposed to theft where despite not as many people coveting it relative to arayos, nevertheless many more people slip up there due to their perception of it as a less severe aveirah.
